# How can I dynamically specify series colours for kendo pie chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, pie-chart, kendo-chart

Is there a way to specify kendo pie chart series colours dynamically? I understand we can specify the colours on the chart initialisation like this:

```
seriesColors: ["#4C9486", "#E86F5E", "#FFD266", "#E6321B", "#8A8F84", "#D86B00", "#F47787"]
```

But I want to do this based on the data fields, i.e. have specific colours for specific fields. Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what you mean by data fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the configuration option `series.colorField`. http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/chart#configuration-series.colorField

A simple example.

```
<div id="chart"></div>
<script>
$("#chart").kendoChart({
    series: [{
        colorField: "valueColor",
        data: [
            { value: 1, valueColor: "red" },
            { value: 2, valueColor: "green" }
        ]
    }]
});
</script>
```

Comment: how can we do this valueColor to be picked randomly instead we have to specify still value